# Dictionary Component or source code that can check in multiple languages

Tags: delphi, dictionary, vcl, ansi, indic

We are developing an application in which we need to implement spell checking for Indic languages that use ANSI fonts (not UNICODE)

I am looking for a Dictionary Component or Source Code that will allow:

- To maintain separate dictionaries
  like for example Legal, commercial,
  etc.
- Support more than one language
- If possible to allow developer to set
  parsing parameters so that we as
  developers can determine as to how
  given text should be broken down in
  words
- Support Addition of words to
  dictionary (should maintain separate
  dictionary and not modify original
  dictionary)
- Support custom dialog box so we can
  design our own dialog box (if
  required)
- Should be able to distinguish case of
  characters meaning it should not
  consider **cascade** and **Cascade**
  as same (if possible). There should be
  some kind of parameters that will
  allow us to enable/disable this feature

If this dictionary can check spellings in another Windows App that would be an added advantage.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/717222/spellcheck-components-for-delphi

Comment: Thanks for suggestions. This post covers my partial requirements only. What I want is a VCL that will allow me to set the rules according to which a given chunk of text is parsed and broken down into words.

I have not found any which will allow this.

Do you know of any with such features?

Answer (score 1):

As the link in the comment suggest, I would look at [Addict component suite and plus pack](http://www.addictivesoftware.com/products.htm).
[Dictionary wizard](http://www.addictivesoftware.com/dictwiz.htm) provide way of creating specialized dictionaries. There's also APIs  "allowing for text parsing, dictionary lookup, text corrections, misspelling suggestions, thesaurus contexts and more."

> Addict was written and designed from
>   the ground up to be as robust and
>   flexible as possible. Developers have
>   complete API access to all of Addict's
>   core features, including main
>   dictionaries, control parsers, parsing
>   engine, entities to ignore while
>   parsing, custom dictionaries,
>   suggestions generation, thesaurus
>   file, and much more.

Comment: I have tried Addict. But the documentation like all VCL components is very bad. the features that you are referring to is not documented anywhere in their help.

The demo provided is also not that informative.

Have you got any source code samples that you can share with me?

I also tried the ActiveX version of Addict but that also does not contain any documentation covering features that you are mentioning.

BTW I am trying out Addict 3.x.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You should split **spellchecker core** system and your **UI**.

So, in your application, you should add any dialog boxes and configuration.
Spellchecker core just works with plain text and returns list or errors with suggestions.

There are dozens of open-source spellchecker core implementations. You can even use online services like Google's one (look at Google Wave videos).

Comment: I have tried many spell checkers but I have always found that they seem to break up words in their own way instead of let the developer decide as to how a word should be broken. In short their parsing system is not customizable.

That is bad news. Do you know of any which will allow us to set parsing rules?